# What is the name of $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2dF(x)$?

Tags: distributions, distance

Is there a statistical distance between two 1-dim distribution F and G that
$D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2dF(x)$?

Or to symmetrize it, take $D^s(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2dF(x)+dG(x)$

If not, why? (What are the main disadvantages?)

I learned that $D_E(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2dx$ is famous. But what about $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dx$?
I want to check relevant materials for learning, but don't known how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's called Cramer-Von Mises distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10485252.2017.1285029?journalCode=gnst20

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: And do you know if there is a distance with form like $\int (F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dx$ or $\int (F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dF(x)$